# Java get ressources as stream always returns null

Tags: java, image

I am trying to load an image using an InputStream. However when I load my image, it always returns null. Here is my project structure :

```
project
--+ src
----+ chess
------+ model
--------+ piece
----------+ Piece.java
------+ assets
--------+ icons
----------+ piece
------------+ rook_black.png
```

And the path I use to access the image is : `./src/chess/assets/icons/piece/rook_black.png`

I have tried to show all the files in the directoryfrom `Piece.java` it works  :

```
String path = "./src/chess/assets/icons/piece/";
File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();

for (File file: files) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

My actual code is :

```
public Image getImage() {
    String path = "./src/chess/assets/icons/piece/rook_black.png";
    InputStream image = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);

    if (image != null) {
        return new Image(image);
    }

    System.out.println("No " + toString() + " image in " + path);
    return null;
}
```

This code actually outputs that `No rook image in ./src/chess/assets/icons/piece/rook_black.png` but I want the InputStream to not be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you must think in terms of **compiled** resources, which means you must think about how the JAR artifact looks. There is no `src` folder.

[image]

Indeed, what you need is

```
final String path = "/chess/assets/icons/piece/rook_black.png";
```

which is an *absolute* path, starting from the *root*.